# B2B extension for allowing users create other users

Tags: customer, customer-group, customer-account, b2b

We have a site where a user needs the ability to create another user and have that user account linked to their account. Think of a store owner that has employees and the store owner needs to create employee accounts. Orders that are placed by employees need to be seen by the owner, possible approval and what not.

It wouldn't make sense in this case to make them admins, there is already functionality to make it so you have to be registered to view the site.

I figured that has to be an extension for this, as this is about the 3rd time a request like this has came to us. Before actually building it out I figured I would look for something but I can't find anything.